# Returning a string from a list

Tags: python

I have code trying to reverse a string from a list using Python, and cannot use the traditional methods as part of the exercise (I cannot mutate a list while iterating, I must do it recursively) but my function does not return my string, not sure what the issue could be:

```
list1 = []

def reverse(text):
    note = ''
    for x in text:
        list1.append(x)
    print list1

#    for x in list1:
#        note = note+list1.pop()

    def recursive(toRev):
        if not list1:
                print toRev, 'Last toRev'
                return toRev

        else:
                toRev = toRev+list1.pop()
                recursive(toRev)
        print toRev, 'Note with in the loop'

        #recursive(toRev)


    finalvar = recursive(note)
    print finalvar, ' :Final'
    return finalvar

reverse('Python!')
```

Comment: Can you explain better what you're trying to do and what the parameters of (I assume) the assignment are? There's no need to have a list or recursion at all if the goal is for `reverse('Hello')` to return `'olleH'`. You can do that with slicing or the built-in `reversed` function as documented on SO numerous times.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist It's a pretty common exercise to have students write their own reversing functions using recursion. The OP mentioned in the question that they are not allowed to use built-in methods.

Comment: @CactusWoman You must have better glasses than I do. I searched for the phrase "built-in" and could only find it in our two comments. What the OP says is, "you can not use traditional(and better) ways" so I was wondering if we could get a little more guidance on what that means, and what is actually required.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything with the result of the recursive call, and aren't passing it back up the chain. 
Try changing `recursive` to:

```
def recursive(toRev):
    if not list1:
        print toRev, 'Last toRev'
        return toRev
    else:
        toRev = toRev+list1.pop()
        print toRev, 'Note with in the loop'
        return recursive(toRev)
```

Comment: I see, it makes sense! I have to return recursively toRev but i have a better solution thanks to your words of wisdom:

Comment: @guyinaboxshell Ok, changed to fit that requirement.

Comment: typo in `return = recursive(toRev)`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are just missing a `return` in the `recursive` function. Also you should define `list1` inside the function, not outside of it.

```
def reverse(text):
    list1 = [] # defined inside of function
    note = ''
    for x in text:
        list1.append(x)
    #print list1

#    for x in list1:
#        note = note+list1.pop()

    def recursive(toRev):
        if not list1:
               #print toRev, 'Last toRev'
                return toRev

        else:
                toRev = toRev+list1.pop()
                return recursive(toRev) # added return
        #print toRev, 'Note with in the loop'

        #recursive(toRev)


    finalvar = recursive(note)
    #print finalvar, ' :Final'
    return finalvar

reverse('Python!')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! figured it out the returning function thing.

Answer (score 0):

Answer thanks to StephenTG

```
list1 = []

    def reverse(text):
        note = ''
        for x in text:
            list1.append(x)
        print list1

    #    for x in list1:
    #        note = note+list1.pop()

        def recursive(toRev):
            if not list1:
                    print toRev, 'Last toRev'
                    return toRev

            else:
                    toRev = toRev+list1.pop()
                    return recursive(toRev)
                    #return toRev
            print toRev, 'Note with in the loop'

            #recursive(toRev)


        finalvar = recursive(note)
        print finalvar, ' :Final'
        return finalvar

    reverse('Python!')
```